# To list only deleted paths from svn log command

Tags: shell, svn, scripting

I'm new to shell scripting. I want to list only deleted file paths from svn repository for particular date range.

I know I should use

svn log -v -r {2013-12-01}:{2014-01-31} url
but this command shows me all the details and all added modified and deleted paths.

I want to display only deleted paths list like this.

D /trunk/file1
D /branch/file1
.
.
.
what should grep, awk?
I tried using it but sometimes it shows me log messages also..
Any solution or script for this.

Comment: `svn log | grep "D /"` ?!

Comment: That will possibly match some comments, too.

Answer (score 0):

With `svn log` it is a little difficult to get the output as per your requirement.

You need to use `svn log -v --xml | grep 'action="[D]"'` and need to do some filtering to get files within the date range.

The easy way is to use `svn diff` instead of `svn log`.

`svn diff -r{2014-01-10}:{2014-01-15} http://hostname/svn/repos/my/path --summarize | grep -e '^D '`
`